# Berkeley DB -ldb_cxx not found

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm building an application that requires Berkeley DB (http://www.resiprocate.org). I am building on OS X, and I had to install Berkeley DB since the machine did not already have it. However, the reSIProcate package I am trying to build cannot find the db_cxx library (`-ldb_cxx`). The installed Berkeley DB `lib` directory only has the following files:

```
libdb-5.3.a
libdb-5.3.dylib
libdb-5.4.la
libdb.a
```

What exactly is `db_cxx`...is `-ldb_cxx` outdated? Or is there some option I need to specify when installing Berkeley DB to create and install a db_cxx library?

Answer (score 0):

libdb-cxx is API needed for c++, it is not being built by default.
To build libdb-cxx, go to the directory where you had built Berkeley Db, then

```
cd build_unix
../dist/configure --enable-cxx
make
sudo make install
```