# Ubuntu Make File Errors

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to make file an exe for a script coin. I have installed the necessary dependencies but am getting the following errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb_cxx
```

Comment: If you can post the Makefile, would be much esier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the boost libraries

> sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Comment: I was so sure I had installed those -_-

That got rid of all the "boost" errors, but I am still stuck with 

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb_cxx

Comment: @user3170725 might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403513/berkeley-db-ldb-cxx-not-found